# add multiple rows in one column using angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, html

I want to generate table contents using json object. I am using ng-repeat to insert multiple rows in a table. But I have to generate table like the following.

```
    --------------
    ID | subjects 
    --------------
       | S1  
    1  | S2  
       | S3  
    --------------
       | S4  
    2  | S5  
       | S6
    --------------


my angular code is: 
 <tr ng-repeat = "user in users">
    <td>{{user.id}}</td>
    <td>{{user.subject}}</td>
</tr>
```

my json object is :

```
user:[
  {id:1 , 
   subjects:[
       {id:1 , name:"eng"} 
       {id:2 , name:"phy"}
   ]
  },
  {id:2 , 
   subjects:[
       {id:1 , name:"eng"} 
       {id:3 , name:"math"}
   ]
  }
]
```

I want to generate html table like this

```
 <table>
  <tr>
     <td >ID</td>
     <td>Sub</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">1</td>
    <td>S1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>S2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>S3</td>
   </tr>
```

how to insert multiple rows in one column using angular

Comment: Flatten the array first, and then run the repeater on the flattened array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`. For example:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="user in users">
    <td rowspan="{{user.subjects.length+1}}">{{user.id}}</td>                    
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="subject in user.subjects">
    <td>S{{subject.id}}</td>
</tr>
```

Here is a full example:

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {

    var users = [{
        id: 1,
        subjects: [{
            id: 1,
            name: "eng"
        }, {
            id: 2,
            name: "phy"
        }]
    }, {
        id: 2,
        subjects: [{
            id: 1,
            name: "eng"
        }, {
            id: 3,
            name: "math"
        }, {
            id: 4,
            name: "hist"
        }, 
        {
            id: 5,
            name: "geog"
        }]
    }];

    $scope.users = users;
});
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
td { border: 1px solid Black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Subjects</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat-start="user in users">
            <td rowspan="{{user.subjects.length+1}}">{{user.id}}</td>                    
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="subject in user.subjects">
            <td>S{{subject.id}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Also, working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/donal/r51d5fw5/17/

An alternative version, using nested `ng-repeat`, can be implemented using a `div` to display the nested subject information:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users">
    <td>{{user.id}}</td>
    <td>
        <div ng-repeat="subject in user.subjects">S{{subject.id}}</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer I have edit my question and explain what kind of html table i want to generate. You add div inside td but I want to add rows inside td @Donal

Comment: @AminaYousuf ok, I was able to implement what you want using ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end.

Answer (score 0):

`rowspan` will do everything you need. Follow this link:

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) This is one of the best resources for web development.

Comment: How will rowspan iterate over the subjects in user.subjects? ;-)

Comment: `rowspan` the label and use Angular to iterate over the subjects. `rowspan` is just the layout. You can also use the answer right above mine.

Comment: Nah I was just messing with your choice of words. Since rowspan doesnt do everything he asked help about. It also isn't necessary to use rowspan if he nests the user.subjects iteration in 1 single td (as according to his question is what he wants to achieve)

Comment: @msinnes is right about rowspan..if i set my id's column rowspan to my subjects length and then add multiple rows in td , i tried it but not able to make it .

Comment: It'll work, but @Donal's answer is much easier to code. I would stick with that. Doing it strictly with a table is going to be a little more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Using div u can also do

```
<div ng-repeat = "user in users">
<div> {{user.id}} </div>
  <div ng-repeat = "user1 in users.subjects">
     {{user1.id}} : {{user1.name}}
  <div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont want to add div I want to add rows in td @Flash

Answer (score 0):

Donal's answer is good.
But I edited to show beautiful table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-height m-b-xs">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Subjects</td>
        <td>name</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="user in users">
        <td rowspan="{{user.subjects.length}}">key {{user.id}}</td>
        <td>S{{ user.subjects[0].id }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.subjects[0].name }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="subject in user.subjects.slice(1)">
        <td>S{{subject.id}}</td>
        <td>{{subject.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```