# Filling data in a table with multiple subheaders

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table where its second column consists of multiple subheaders. For each row in the table, its data under the second column can consist of multiple rows. I’m having trouble syncing those multiple rows under the subheaders.

http://jsfiddle.net/jkkvy86x/

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col 1</th>
      <th colspan="3">col2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>h1</th>
      <th>h2</th>
      <th>h3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>row1</td>
      <td>data1</td>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data4</td>
      <td>data5</td>
      <td>data6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row2</td>
      <td>data1</td>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>data3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

For row1, I want data4, data5, data6 to also be under h1, h2, h3, respectively.

I'm doing this in AngularJS/Bootstrap so the data/formatting is important.  I don't think adding another row with a blank data for its first column would work although I'm open to solutions.

Comment: Do you have a example with a dummy data. I wanna help you! But the data structure will help.

Comment: I found a similar answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30915100/add-multiple-rows-in-one-column-using-angular-ng-repeat

I'm having trouble with getting the rows to lineup since my data in the first column has multiple lines: http://jsfiddle.net/c9fm3eur/

Comment: I can help u! We can do that design with: - Bootstrap, CSS, or even Flex! Just let me know :) @Geno

You are working with tables and that is ok! But the design which you want is advanced and we can use a better tool to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not angular. BTW, can you use `<br/>`?

I was working on a plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/XNQPnHM1z58XB5usioZA?p=preview

But with the structure I can do a better suggestion.