# Inseting table inside table in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

With reference to this code,if I am having three columcolumns (eg: including mrks after sub and the mrkd also have different number of rows like subjects.What change should I do now?

[add multiple rows in one column using angular ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30915100/add-multiple-rows-in-one-column-using-angular-ng-repeat/30915225#30915225?newreg=9654ec50208845e6aa9ae4fa48d2d7ab)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the fiddle mentioned in the answer of mentioned question.
I have just added below code in html :
`<td>{{subject.mark}}</td>`

And added the mark in users object. 
Please refer [UpdatedFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36caum18/)

Comment: Thanks for that. and I want to display in the manner like the S1 is also subdivided into 3 rows and S2 is subdivided into 4 rows and goes on.... Is there any way like that?